# Pandas: counting consecutive rows with condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

```
name = ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b']
fillrate = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]
df = pd.DataFrame(name)
df.columns = ['name']
df['fillrate'] = fillrate
```

I want to create a column like this:

```
df['count'] = [1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
```

Explanation: the 'count' column resets to 1 when there's a new name, OR when fill rate increases; otherwise, 'count' column equals to the last value plus 1.

It's easy to do it using loops, but I'd like to avoid this since the data is huge. Is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? Also, why are you adding columns and their names like, instead of setting them in the constructor?

Answer (score 5):

IIUC let us combine `shift` with `diff` and using `cumsum` create the sub-group, `cumcount`

```
s=(df.name.ne(df.name.shift()) | df.fillrate.diff().gt(0)).cumsum()
s.groupby(s).cumcount()+1
Out[17]: 
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    1
6    2
7    3
8    1
dtype: int64
```